# Embedded monotouch debugging

Tags: ios, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have successfully embedded mono into an existing iphone app. There are some issues that I need to debug in the code on the mono side on the device. The issue I'm seeing is only happening on the device. The xcode debugger obviously can't help me. Is there a way to debug the embedded mono code using MonoDevelop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the part of your app that initializes the Mono runtime, you need to initialize the Mono soft debugger, and make it connect to the host machine's IP.

Then you need to have MonoDevelop listening for a debugger connection. For MonoTouch, this is done using a custom addin, but there's a secret command that allows directly connecting the soft debugger for any project. It's enabled using the `MONODEVELOP_SDB_TEST` environment variable: Run->Run with...->Custom Soft Debugger.

Comment: That's the part that I couldn't figure out. I couldn't see a way to connect the debugger to my app. I've moved on to a new way of doing things that doesn't require this, so I can't verify that this works.

Answer (score 0):

This is a special/uncommon case. I'm pretty sure you'll need to include code, inside your application, that will communicate with the MonoDevelop debugger (just like MonoTouch applications includes). Look at monodevelop debugger addins for source code samples.

You can also try to use gdb when using the simulator. Launch the simulator with

```
 /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/mtouch -v -v --debugsim=your/application.app
```

and inside another terminal

```
 gdb --pid XXXXX
```

where XXXXX is the PID that mtouch printed on the terminal.

Comment: One requirement that I didn't mention is that I need to debug on the device. Looking closer at the main.m that mtouch --xcode generates it looks like there is some code related to connecting to the debugger. I'll take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that this is possible.